# How to PHP pass a public method ClassName.methodName() to 'unserialize_callback_func' when call `ini_set`?

Tags: php, serialization, methods, pass-by-reference, deserialization

As `example #2` in this offical [site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) from php.org, to avoid unkown classname, we provide `include` call to the definition of the serialized classes.

```
<?php
$serialized_object='O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}';

// unserialize_callback_func directive available as of PHP 4.2.0
ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'mycallback'); // set your callback_function

function mycallback($classname) 
{
    // just include a file containing your classdefinition
    // you get $classname to figure out which classdefinition is required
}
?>
```

My question is if `mycallback` is a public method of class C, how can we pass it as a parameter when calling `ini_set`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is if `mycallback` is a public method of class C, how can we pass it as a parameter when calling `ini_set`?

I think you can't do that for a standard public function of an object, because [`unserialize_callback_func`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/var.configuration.php#unserialize-callback-func) is a string setting, but a [callback](http://php.net/callback#language.types.callback) of an object function is an `Array`.

But if you make it a `static` public function, you can pass it as a string:

```
class C
{
    public static function mycallback($classname) 
    {
        // just include a file containing your classdefinition
        // you get $classname to figure out which classdefinition is required
    }
}

ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'C::mycallback'); // set your callback_function
```

Which might be the better alternative. Otherwise you can wrap it into a standard function as well:

```
function c_mycallback_wrapper($classname)
{
    $c = new C;
    return $c->mycallback($classname);
}
ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'c_mycallback_wrapper');
```

Another alternative is, that you make use of [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) (e.g. [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)). [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) supports autoloading, but I don't know if autoloading is something that helps you in your case, often it does.

Comment: `Warning: ini_set() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in ... on line ...` is what I get when passing `array($c, 'mycallback')`

Comment: @NamGiVU: Yeah how I assumed, I checked this as well and edited the question a bit, more links and a better explanation. I also elaborated the example with the wrapper function.

Comment: @NamGiVU: As you're looking for a static class function example, I added it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it is done

```
<?php 
class C {
    var $serialized_object='O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}'; 

    function mycallback($classname)  
    { 
        // just include a file containing your classdefinition 
        // you get $classname to figure out which classdefinition is required 
    } 

}

$c = new C();

// unserialize_callback_func directive available as of PHP 4.2.0 
ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'C::mycallback'); // set your callback_function 

unserialize($c->serialized_object);
?>
```

Comment: I guess you need to add `static` for the method. With that your answer is the accepted one :)

Comment: I'm sorry I failed to use that without static though